# How to get the QNX Kernel source code?

Tags: svn, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I'm wondering how could I fetch the latest version of QNX kernel source code? I've tried the following command:

```
svn checkout --username <username> http://community.qnx.com/svn/repos/coreos_pub/trunk
```

while replacing  with my email address I can login [QNX Developer Community](http://www.qnx.com/account/login.html) but it seems I don't have access. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: `cW54X3NvdXJjZS5pc28=` use base64 decoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer to that question might be that you cannot get it that way. Quoting Wikipedia:

"On April 9, 2010, Research In Motion announced they would acquire QNX Software Systems from Harman International Industries.[1] On the same day, **QNX source code access was restricted**.[10] In September 2010, the company announced a tablet computer, the BlackBerry PlayBook, and a new operating system BlackBerry Tablet OS based on QNX to run on the tablet.[11]"

Also: [link](http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.community/wiki/UpdatedQNXSourceAccessPolicyFAQ)

Comment: http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.core_os/wiki/GetTheOSSource

Comment: But then, if you click "policy for source access" link on the site you linked, it says "Please contact your QNX Sales or Support representative if you require access to QNX source code.". It appears that you need to contact them in order to obtain username for svn (as opposed to username on their site).

Answer (score 3):

QNX is not open-source and you need to complete a legal procedure before you can gain access to QNX source code.  You need to contact either your QNX sales or technical support representative for the details of the procedure.  There is absolutely no other legal way to gain access to the source code.  This also implies that you cannot gain access to the source code unless you are a legitimate QNX customer.